# Looking for "hung socket simulator" for testing socket timeouts

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am testing handling for socket timeout conditions - for example, connection timeout, connect but no accept, accept but won't read, etc.

I'm looking for a program/script that will act as a server socket producing these effects.

This "hung socket simulator" needs to run on Mac OS (or Linux).

Comment: Not sure what you're after?  What language are you bound to?  No language?  Why not use Java, catch the SocketTimeoutException() during the accept/read/write functions.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a program to simulate these conditions on the server side.  I am agnostic to what the program is written in as long as it can run on MacOS or Linux.

Comment: The Network Link Conditioner tool that comes with XCode could be used to simulate some network problems ( https://tarikdahic.com/posts/using-network-link-conditioner-to-simulate-bad-network-conditions-on-ios-and-macos/ ) -- outside of that, it's quite easy to write a simple network server that doesn't work correctly; so easy that most people end up doing that even when they aren't trying to :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one called Bane: https://github.com/danielwellman/bane.

Answer (score 4):

I think the powerful tool [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) might be helpful here, it can redirect the request to the real endpoint and thus, you can have full control to the socat process itself to simulate what you want (like suspending the process at certain phase by kill -stop or so)

one of my use cases is that I just want my client app to finish the handshake with the remote service but read no more data:

```
 socat -d -d -d TCP-LISTEN:22181,fork SYSTEM:'socat - "TCP:the-remote-host:2181" \| dd bs=1 count=50' &
```

the above example only send the first 50 bytes of the response back.

Comment: just to clarify, from the example, you can see that with socat, you can even excute any script before sending the request or getting the response. And with the '-d -d -d' options, you can get the richest debug info, which is very helpful for you to analyse the packets back and forth. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just start your client program on your dev machine and when you want the TimeOut to appear, just unplug your network cable.

Comment: First, that won't simulate a timeout.  You'll get a "no route to host" immediately.   Second I need to simulate multiple types of timeouts (see question).

Comment: I think you're supposed to connect first, then pull the plug.

Comment: Third, I want to automate the tests, like in CI.  I can't pull the cable in CI.

Answer (score 0):

For the use case of an HTTP server that accepts connections and then hangs, here's a short Python script I use, timeout-server.py, which I [found here](https://gist.github.com/dansimau/9779050?permalink_comment_id=3522921#gistcomment-3522921)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time



class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(s):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1000)


class TimeoutServer(HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, hostname, port):
        HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address=(hostname, port),
                            RequestHandlerClass=RequestHandler)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    server = TimeoutServer('127.0.0.1', 9000)

    print('Will listen on %s:%i' % server.server_address)

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--ssl':
        import ssl
        server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, certfile=sys.argv[2],
                                        server_side=True)
        print('SSL enabled.')

    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```